# How to avoid SQL Injection in SQL query with Like % Operator. only php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, security

How to avoid SQL Injection in SQL query with Like Operator for only PHP and Mysql?
 can this be done using string functions?

or can anybody tell me what should I  do to prevent attacks of like % operator?

Comment: Use the LIKE "%SEARCH%" bar at the top.

Comment: personally I use a framework like CodeIgniter, its less boilerplate + security stuff to worry about, I wouldn't dream of doing php from ground up ever again.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: Actually my question was, how to prevent the user from using like%... he can perform sql injection using the  like % clause, how to prevent this attack..

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the string using `mysql_real_escape_string` and add the `%` wildcards afterwards.

Comment: you can even escape the whole string including `%` – they do not have a special meaning for escaping

Comment: True. Didn't think of that. Oh well.. It's one (or two) less characters in the string to escape. Could save you a nanosecond per year. ;)

Comment: minus the time to concatenate the strings :p but yeah, it really does not matter

Comment: You will need to concatinate anyway, because the search string is user input. :) And you could include the wildcards in your query already, which will actually save a concatination. ;)

Answer (score 2):

When you run the query use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) as follows:

```
mysql_query("SELECT field FROM table WHERE field2 LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($yourVar)."%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you could do to make it secure.
First of you have to figure out what type of data you will be searching: number, string etc.

I would suggest using PHP's **PDO library**, preparing the query and binding the value according to the data type you should receive.
Below an example where the received data is supposed to be string. Notice the `PARAM_STR`.

```
...

$value = "apple";

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM fruit WHERE type LIKE :something');
$sth->bindParam(':something', '%'.$something.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

...
```